# Nanoid Typescript in a cloud function - Error: typeof import has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, api, google-cloud-functions

Importing

```
import * as customAlphabet from "nanoid";
var id: string = ""
const alphabet: string = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

function generateID() {
      id = customAlphabet(alphabet,10)
      console.log(id)
}
```

**Error**

```
id = customAlphabet(alphabet,10)

This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("/Users/../API/functions/node_modules/nanoid/index")' has no call signatures.
```

Comment: Have you installed [`@types/nanoid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/nanoid)?

Comment: yeps, installed that

Comment: tried id = (customAlphabet as any)(alphabet,10) ... it isn't throwing an error now, but no clue how to fix it any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need call `customAlphabet` on the [imported module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-the-entire-module-into-a-single-variable-and-use-it-to-access-the-module-exports). This gives you a generator function. You can call this generator to generate your random string using your custom alphabet set and custom length.

```ts
import * as nanoid from "nanoid";

// Your alphabet set
const alphabet = '0123456789ABCD';

// generator is a function that returns a random string
// of length 10, with alphabets from the characters in `alphabet` constant 
const generator = nanoid.customAlphabet(alphabet, 10);

// some random string
console.log(generator());
// another random string
console.log(generator());
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-nanoid-ts-forked-mhwqj)

Comment: Thanks Bhai! this worked. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @r2Dragon if this answer has helped you solve your problem, please consider [upvoting and accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157936).